# Client side error checking not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:[image]

The html code which is basically just two input fields inside a form called regForm:

```
<div>
   <label for="regName">
      <span>Name</span>
      <span class="error" 
         ng-show="regCheckNamesMessage">{{regCheckNamesMessage}}</span>
  </label>
  <div>
     <span class="inputIcon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></span>
     <input autocomplete="off"
         id="regFirstName"
         name="regFirstName"
         ng-change="regCheckNames(regForm.regFirstName, regForm.regLastName)"
         ng-model="regFirstName"
         ng-required="true"
         ng-minlength="2"
         placeholder="First Name"/>
     <input autocomplete="off"
         id="regLastName"
         name="regLastName"
         ng-change="regCheckNames(regForm.regFirstName, regForm.regLastName)"
         ng-model="regLastName"
         ng-required="true"
         ng-minlength="2"
         placeholder="Last Name"
         type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have the following javascript code that does some checking for required fields:

```
regCheckNames = (regFirstName, regLastName) => {   
   if (regFirstName.$dirty == true && regLastName.$dirty == true) {
        if (regFirstName.$error.required == true && regLastName.$error.required == true) {
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "Both are required";
        } else {
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "";
        }
    }

    if (regFirstName.$dirty == true && regLastName.$dirty == false) {
        if (regFirstName.$error.required == true)
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "First name is required";
        else
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "";
    }

    if (regFirstName.$dirty == false && regLastName.$dirty == true) {
        if (regLastName.$error.required == true)
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "Last name is required";
        else
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "";
    }
}
```

Somehow the checking code is not working the way I expect it to work. I wanted the error `Both are required` to appear whenever the user left both fields blank after touching the fields, the error `First name is required` when the user touch the first name field but left it blank and so on. Anyone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it to be an if else. Otherwise the third error message will override the previous errors when both fields are dirty.

```
regCheckNames = (regFirstName, regLastName) => {   
   if (regFirstName.$dirty == true && regLastName.$dirty == true) {
        if (regFirstName.$error.required == true && regLastName.$error.required == true) {
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "Both are required";
        } else {
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "";
        }
    } else if (regFirstName.$dirty == true && regLastName.$dirty == false) {
        if (regFirstName.$error.required == true)
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "First name is required";
        else
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "";
    } else if (regFirstName.$dirty == false && regLastName.$dirty == true) {
        if (regLastName.$error.required == true)
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "Last name is required";
        else
            this.regCheckNamesMessage = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of angular you are using, but you might want to have a look at the [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) and [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) directives. This is a proper way of displaying error messages.

You could use something like this:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.regFirstName.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">First name is required</div>
  </div>
<div ng-messages="myForm.regFirstName.$error && myForm.regLastName.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Both are required</div>
</div>
```

You can have a look [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOgpwB?editors=101)